# Efficient way of sending a large bit stream in an HTTP response

Tags: javascript, algorithm, rest

I need to send large string representing a number over a wire to the client written in Java Script. In theory it's a stream of `0s` and `1s`, like: `011101011101101...`, but it can be very, very big (millions of bits in length). My goal, of course, is to minimize necessary processing and sending overhead. I thought about changing the base number of that string, so that it uses HEX or larger radix which would greately reduce the amount of data that has to be sent. JavaScript has built in functions for converting to and from different numbering systems so it looked like the way to go. However, the maximum supported radix is just 36. My calculations are showing that when having a stream of 50 mln bits and using 36 radix, then you still need `1,388,888` characters to be sent - way too much.

My question is - do you know any way that would help to achieve my goal? Some constraints:

- Solution must work for streams of arbitrary length
- bit streams can be as large as 50mln bits
- Good performance should be guaranteed for length around 1-10mln bits. For larger streams it should still work, however it doesn't have to scale up linearly
- I would put more emphasis on optimizing the amount of data that has to be sent, not necessarily on reducing the CPU overhead

Comment: I did something like this a while ago, i used typed arrays (no legacy browser support) and jquery. What server-side language do you use? I could post either just the client script or both client+server examples. And this is no rocket science, i am not sure if this is the super correct way of doing this, but it worked great for us. This would send the data in binary format, eg. you do not need to encode/decode your numbers to/from strings

Comment: Have you thought about introducing some kind of a simple compression? For example, instead of sending 111100000, you can send 1405, where the number after 0/1 represents the number of occurrences.

Comment: @MiljenMikic I tried LZ77 compression on binary strings, but it only reduced 64k stream to around 36k. This is not even a half :(

Comment: Why do you need to send it as string ? it's not like js can't cope with binary response from the webservice, am I wrong ?

Comment: @psychollek, you might be right that wrapping with a String is not required. However, the real question is about how to reduce the overhead of sending 10 mln bits.

Comment: if compresion directly on bits does not help you much - then the only option is to think if you could throw away some information - you can't really overcome the fact of 10mln bits being about 2MB (including protocol overhead).

Comment: What kind of data are you sending? You said you had a string representing a (large) number, so i guess you mean a very large number? You could try to make a formula for the number and send the formula instead?

Comment: @Snellface, exactly right - very large number. I will have plenty of those and there is no uniformed formula to derive that numbers.

Comment: Whatever radix you use to convert a number into a string you will not shrink the size any smaller then sending the data as a binary stream. The only way to shrink it further is to use a compression algorithm, and my advice is to use something that is well tested and efficient rather then trying to write your own compression algorithm. What format are you going to store your data in at the client-side? The largest number (in the latest version of chrome) is 1.7976931348623157e+308, which is a very large number, but it is still only represented by 8 bytes (64 bits), and it's not a 100% accurate.

Comment: @Snellface, I think you are right on the Radix being worse than raw binary stream. So the follow up question is, how make such stream most compact?

Comment: To make it as compact as possible you would have to use some kind of compression, i have never used any programmatically and because of this i can't point you to any good (free or commercial) ones. Other then that, if you send your data as a binary stream you would have to either know the size of your data to be the same every time, or perferably, you would send the size of the data first, as an int 32, so that the receiving javascript knows how much to parse. And if you are going to send more then 1 you could start off by sending the number of "big numbers" to read.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (the demo has been written with no way of testing it, but it "should work™", here is a fiddle for those who wants to copy/cut/paste: http://fiddle.jshell.net/sywz3aym/2/
Please note the fiddle can't run, i had intended to write a responder but i can't right now i'm afraid.

At the bottom of the javascript entry area i have comment section of how a asp.net responder could look, it uses a "Generic Handler (.ashx)" file if you use visual studio, if you use any other language you will have to use the equivalent options there. You need a request responder which you can customize to return binary data, you need to set the Content-Type to "application/octet-stream" (octet for those who do not know = "group of 8", eg. a byte :))

And here is the javascript + comment as in a glorious wall of text format:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = 'your handler URL';
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open('GET', url, true);
    oReq.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
        var buffer = oReq.response;
        var yourData = ExtractData(buffer);
    }
    oReq.send(null);
});

function ExtractData(buffer) {
    var dataReader = {
        dataView: new DataView(buffer),
        readPtr: 0,

        littleEndian: (function () {
            var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(2);
            new DataView(buffer).setInt16(0, 256, true);
            return new Int16Array(buffer)[0] === 256;
        })(),

        setReadPtrOffset: function (byteIndex) {
            this.readPtr = byteIndex;
        },

        nextInt8: function () {
            var data = this.dataView.getInt8(this.readPtr);
            this.readPtr += 1; // Sizeof int
            return data;
        },
        nextUint8: function () {
            var data = this.dataView.getUint8(this.readPtr);
            this.readPtr += 1; // Sizeof int8
            return data;
        },

        nextInt32: function () {
            var data = this.dataView.getInt32(this.readPtr, this.littleEndian);
            this.readPtr += 4; // Sizeof int32
            return data;
        },
        nextUint32: function () {
            var data = this.dataView.getUint32(this.readPtr, this.littleEndian);
            this.readPtr += 4; // Sizeof uint32
            return data;
        },

        nextFloat32: function () {
            var data = this.dataView.getFloat32(this.readPtr, this.littleEndian);
            this.readPtr += 4; // Sizeof float
            return data;
        },
        nextFloat64: function () {
            var data = this.dataView.getFloat64(this.readPtr, this.littleEndian);
            this.readPtr += 8; // Sizeof double
            return data;
        },

        nextUTF8String: function (length) {
            var data = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(this.dataView.buffer, this.readPtr, length));
            this.readPtr += length; // Sizeof int
            return data;
        },
    }

    var numberOfInt32ToRead = dataReader.nextInt32(); // First data could be, for example, the number of ints to read.
    for(var i = 0; i < numberOfInt32ToRead; i++){
        var someInt = dataReader.nextInt32();
        // doStuffWithInt(someInt);
    }
}

/*
Serverside code looks kind of like this (asp.net/c#):

    public class YourVeryNiceDataRequestHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"; // <- very important
            List<int> data = SomeMethodWithGivesYouData();
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)data.Count)); // Explicit type casting only to help me get an overview of the data being sent, in this case it has no functional meaning other then to help me debug
            foreach(int i in data)
            {
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)i));
            }
            // You could send structs as well, either with the help of a binary formatter, or you can do like i did here and use BitConverter.GetBytes, be carefull when sending strings/chars since they are by default (usually) in a widechar format (1 char = 2 bytes), since i only use english for this i can convert it to a UTF8 char (1 byte):                         context.Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(new char[] { (motion.Phase == Phases.Concentric ? 'C' : 'E') })); // Phase (as single char)

        }
    }
*/
```

I hope this either help you directly, or guide you in the correct direction.
**Please note this is VERY dependent on your data types that your server use, and might not fall into your "REST" category, you did however state that you wanted to optimize for stream size and this afaik is the best way to do that, with the exception of adding data compression**
**Javascript typed arrays "mimics" c-style datatypes, like those used in c, c++, c#, java and so forth**

**Disclamer:

I have not tried this with data > 1MB, it did however cut the total size of data being sent from server to client from 2MB down to a few 10-100~KB, and it for the amount of data i send/read the execution time were "not humanly measurable" other then the roundtrip time for the extra request, since this is requested AFTER the page is loaded in the browser**

**Final word of warning: Any manual bit serializing/deserializing should be done with care, since it is very easy to make a mistake forgetting that you have changed something either client or server side, and it will give you un-debuggable garbage if you read or write a byte too much/too little on either end, this is why i add explicit type casting in my server-side code, that way i can open both the server code and the client code side-by-side and match readInt32 to a Write((int)...).

Not a fun job, but it makes things very compact and very fast (normally i would go for readability, but some tasks just have to work faster then readable code).**

Typed arrays can't be used in every browser however, but caniuse state that 85% of the internet could use them: http://caniuse.com/#feat=typedarrays